# git push failed with error remote: The push is attempting to remove commit

Tags: git

Currently I am working in a setup where individual **features** are being developed in separate branches and all are being merged to one single **main** branch.

While syncing the feature branch with main branch, I am getting the below error during push to the remote.
Before push, I executed following commands

```
> feature1_branch$ git push                   #0 : feature1 work pushed
> main_branch$     git merge feature1         #1 : feature1 merged to main
> main_branch$     git merge feature2         #2 : feature2 changes merged to main
> main_branch$     git pull                   #3 : to get all other feature changes to main
> feature1_branch$ git pull                   #4 
> feature1_branch$ git merge main_branch      #5 : to make the feature1 branch aligned with main
> feature1_branch$ git push                   #6 : error
```

The error at `#6` is as below :

```
remote: The push is attempting to remove commit <commit sha> from ref feature1_branch.
```

Please note that the `commit-sha` being displayed in error message is committed to `feature_branch` first and the same is merged already.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [On undoing, fixing, or removing commits in git](https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html)

Comment: You merged *your* `feature1` branch, but is the tip of *your* `feature1` branch the tip of *their* `feature1` branch? The earlier `git push` implies that it probably should be, but perhaps something has changed since then. (Your note that the hash ID matches suggests that it hasn't.) So: alternatively, perhaps their pre-receive or update hook, which produced the error message, has a bug in it.

Comment: @torek: thanks for your reply. Yeah, the pre-receive hook could possibly be the issue..